# Hybris installation errors

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I am trying to install hybris version 4.7.9 in my system and getting following errors. I tried removing the config folder and rebuilding from scratch. still no use.

LOGS:

```
   [yjavac] Arrays cannot be resolved
   [yjavac] ----------
   [yjavac] 447. ERROR in D:\hybris-multichannel-suite-4.7.9\hybris\bin\platform
\ext\servicelayer\src\de\hybris\platform\servicelayer\security\permissions\impl\
DefaultPermissionManagementService.java (at line 261)
   [yjavac]     removePermissionsForPrincipals(item, Arrays.asList(principal));
   [yjavac]                                          ^^^^^^
   [yjavac] Arrays cannot be resolved
   [yjavac] ----------
   [yjavac] 448. ERROR in D:\hybris-multichannel-suite-4.7.9\hybris\bin\platform
\ext\servicelayer\src\de\hybris\platform\servicelayer\security\permissions\impl\
DefaultPermissionManagementService.java (at line 270)
   [yjavac] Could not find missing types in public abstract Set#RAW entrySet()
   [yjavac]     removePermissionsForNames(item, Arrays.asList(permissionName));
   [yjavac]                                     ^^^^^^
   [yjavac] Arrays cannot be resolved
   [yjavac] ----------
   [yjavac] 449. ERROR in D:\hybris-multichannel-suite-4.7.9\hybris\bin\platform
\ext\servicelayer\src\de\hybris\platform\servicelayer\security\permissions\impl\
DefaultPermissionManagementService.java (at line 432)
   [yjavac]     addGlobalPermissions(Arrays.asList(permissionAssignment));
   [yjavac]                          ^^^^^^
   [yjavac] Arrays cannot be resolved
   [yjavac] ----------
   [yjavac] 450. ERROR in D:\hybris-multichannel-suite-4.7.9\hybris\bin\platform
\ext\servicelayer\src\de\hybris\platform\servicelayer\security\permissions\impl\
DefaultPermissionManagementService.java (at line 448)
   [yjavac]     removeGlobalPermissions(Arrays.asList(permissionAssignment));
   [yjavac]                             ^^^^^^
   [yjavac] Arrays cannot be resolved
   [yjavac] ----------
   [yjavac] 451. ERROR in D:\hybris-multichannel-suite-4.7.9\hybris\bin\platform
\ext\servicelayer\src\de\hybris\platform\servicelayer\security\permissions\impl\
DefaultPermissionManagementService.java (at line 465)
   [yjavac]     removeGlobalPermissionsForPrincipals(Arrays.asList(principal));
   [yjavac]                                          ^^^^^^
   [yjavac] Arrays cannot be resolved
   [yjavac] ----------
   [yjavac] 452. ERROR in D:\hybris-multichannel-suite-4.7.9\hybris\bin\platform
\ext\servicelayer\src\de\hybris\platform\servicelayer\security\permissions\impl\
DefaultPermissionManagementService.java (at line 474)
   [yjavac]     removeGlobalPermissionsForNames(Arrays.asList(permissionName));
   [yjavac]                                     ^^^^^^
   [yjavac] Arrays cannot be resolved
   [yjavac] ----------
   [yjavac] 453. ERROR in D:\hybris-multichannel-suite-4.7.9\hybris\bin\platform
\ext\servicelayer\src\de\hybris\platform\servicelayer\security\permissions\impl\
DefaultPermissionManagementService.java (at line 724)
   [yjavac]     for (final Map.Entry<PK, Set<PK>> entry : principalPKToPermissio
nsPKMap.entrySet())
   [yjavac]                ^^^^^^^^^
   [yjavac] Map.Entry cannot be resolved to a type
   [yjavac] ----------
   [yjavac] 454. ERROR in D:\hybris-multichannel-suite-4.7.9\hybris\bin\platform
\ext\servicelayer\src\de\hybris\platform\servicelayer\security\permissions\impl\
DefaultPermissionManagementService.java (at line 724)
   [yjavac]     for (final Map.Entry<PK, Set<PK>> entry : principalPKToPermissio
nsPKMap.entrySet())
   [yjavac]
        ^^^^^^^^
   [yjavac] The method entrySet() from the type Map<PK,Set<PK>> refers to the mi
ssing type Map$Entry
   [yjavac] ----------
   [yjavac] 455. ERROR in D:\hybris-multichannel-suite-4.7.9\hybris\bin\platform
\ext\servicelayer\src\de\hybris\platform\servicelayer\security\permissions\impl\
DefaultPermissionManagementService.java (at line 790)
   [yjavac]     for (final Map.Entry<Principal, List<Boolean>> entry : permissio
nMap.entrySet())
   [yjavac]                ^^^^^^^^^
   [yjavac] Map.Entry cannot be resolved to a type
   [yjavac] ----------
   [yjavac] 456. ERROR in D:\hybris-multichannel-suite-4.7.9\hybris\bin\platform
\ext\servicelayer\src\de\hybris\platform\servicelayer\security\permissions\impl\
DefaultPermissionManagementService.java (at line 790)
   [yjavac]     for (final Map.Entry<Principal, List<Boolean>> entry : permissio
nMap.entrySet())
   [yjavac]
     ^^^^^^^^
   [yjavac] The method entrySet() from the type Map<Principal,List<Boolean>> ref
ers to the missing type Map$Entry
   [yjavac] ----------
   [yjavac] 457. ERROR in D:\hybris-multichannel-suite-4.7.9\hybris\bin\platform
\ext\servicelayer\src\de\hybris\platform\servicelayer\security\permissions\impl\
DefaultPermissionManagementService.java (at line 858)
   [yjavac]     for (final Map.Entry<PrincipalModel, List<PermissionAssignment>>
 entry : groupByPrincipalMap.entrySet())
   [yjavac]                ^^^^^^^^^
   [yjavac] Map.Entry cannot be resolved to a type
   [yjavac] ----------
   [yjavac] 458. ERROR in D:\hybris-multichannel-suite-4.7.9\hybris\bin\platform
\ext\servicelayer\src\de\hybris\platform\servicelayer\security\permissions\impl\
DefaultPermissionManagementService.java (at line 858)
   [yjavac]     for (final Map.Entry<PrincipalModel, List<PermissionAssignment>>
 entry : groupByPrincipalMap.entrySet())
   [yjavac]
                             ^^^^^^^^
   [yjavac] The method entrySet() from the type Map<PrincipalModel,List<Permissi
onAssignment>> refers to the missing type Map$Entry
   [yjavac] ----------
   [yjavac] 459. ERROR in D:\hybris-multichannel-suite-4.7.9\hybris\bin\platform
\ext\servicelayer\src\de\hybris\platform\servicelayer\security\permissions\impl\
DefaultPermissionManagementService.java (at line 912)
   [yjavac]     for (final Map.Entry<PrincipalModel, List<PermissionAssignment>>
 entry : groupByPrincipalMap.entrySet())
   [yjavac]                ^^^^^^^^^
   [yjavac] Map.Entry cannot be resolved to a type
   [yjavac] ----------
   [yjavac] 460. ERROR in D:\hybris-multichannel-suite-4.7.9\hybris\bin\platform
\ext\servicelayer\src\de\hybris\platform\servicelayer\security\permissions\impl\
DefaultPermissionManagementService.java (at line 912)
   [yjavac]     for (final Map.Entry<PrincipalModel, List<PermissionAssignment>>
 entry : groupByPrincipalMap.entrySet())
   [yjavac]
                             ^^^^^^^^
   [yjavac] The method entrySet() from the type Map<PrincipalModel,List<Permissi
onAssignment>> refers to the missing type Map$Entry
   [yjavac] ----------
   [yjavac] 461. ERROR in D:\hybris-multichannel-suite-4.7.9\hybris\bin\platform
\ext\servicelayer\src\de\hybris\platform\servicelayer\security\permissions\impl\
DefaultPermissionManagementService.java (at line 953)
   [yjavac]     for (final Map.Entry<PK, List<PermissionContainer>> entry : grou
pByPrincipalMap.entrySet())
   [yjavac]                ^^^^^^^^^
   [yjavac] Map.Entry cannot be resolved to a type
   [yjavac] ----------
   [yjavac] 462. ERROR in D:\hybris-multichannel-suite-4.7.9\hybris\bin\platform
\ext\servicelayer\src\de\hybris\platform\servicelayer\security\permissions\impl\
DefaultPermissionManagementService.java (at line 953)
   [yjavac]     for (final Map.Entry<PK, List<PermissionContainer>> entry : grou
pByPrincipalMap.entrySet())
   [yjavac]
                ^^^^^^^^
   [yjavac] The method entrySet() from the type Map<PK,List<PermissionContainer>
> refers to the missing type Map$Entry
   [yjavac] ----------
   [yjavac] 463. ERROR in D:\hybris-multichannel-suite-4.7.9\hybris\bin\platform
\ext\servicelayer\src\de\hybris\platform\servicelayer\security\permissions\impl\
DefaultPermissionManagementService.java (at line 1051)
   [yjavac]     for (final Map.Entry<PK, List<PK>> permissionEntry : principalTo
PermissionListMap.entrySet())
   [yjavac]                ^^^^^^^^^
   [yjavac] Map.Entry cannot be resolved to a type
   [yjavac] ----------
   [yjavac] 464. ERROR in D:\hybris-multichannel-suite-4.7.9\hybris\bin\platform
\ext\servicelayer\src\de\hybris\platform\servicelayer\security\permissions\impl\
DefaultPermissionManagementService.java (at line 1051)
   [yjavac]     for (final Map.Entry<PK, List<PK>> permissionEntry : principalTo
PermissionListMap.entrySet())
   [yjavac]
                  ^^^^^^^^
   [yjavac] The method entrySet() from the type Map<PK,List<PK>> refers to the m
issing type Map$Entry
   [yjavac] ----------
   [yjavac] 465. ERROR in D:\hybris-multichannel-suite-4.7.9\hybris\bin\platform
\ext\servicelayer\src\de\hybris\platform\servicelayer\security\permissions\impl\
DefaultPermissionManagementService.java (at line 1223)
   [yjavac]     for (final Map.Entry<Principal, List<Boolean>> entry : permissio
nMap.entrySet())
   [yjavac]                ^^^^^^^^^
   [yjavac] Map.Entry cannot be resolved to a type
   [yjavac] ----------
   [yjavac] 466. ERROR in D:\hybris-multichannel-suite-4.7.9\hybris\bin\platform
\ext\servicelayer\src\de\hybris\platform\servicelayer\security\permissions\impl\
DefaultPermissionManagementService.java (at line 1223)
   [yjavac]     for (final Map.Entry<Principal, List<Boolean>> entry : permissio
nMap.entrySet())
   [yjavac]
     ^^^^^^^^
   [yjavac] The method entrySet() from the type Map<Principal,List<Boolean>> ref
ers to the missing type Map$Entry
   [yjavac] ----------
   [yjavac] ----------
   [yjavac] 467. ERROR in D:\hybris-multichannel-suite-4.7.9\hybris\bin\platform
\ext\servicelayer\src\de\hybris\platform\servicelayer\security\spring\DefaultUse
rToAuthenticationConverter.java (at line 20)
   [yjavac]     import java.util.Arrays;
   [yjavac]            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   [yjavac] The import java.util.Arrays cannot be resolved
   [yjavac] ----------
   [yjavac] 468. ERROR in D:\hybris-multichannel-suite-4.7.9\hybris\bin\platform
\ext\servicelayer\src\de\hybris\platform\servicelayer\security\spring\DefaultUse
rToAuthenticationConverter.java (at line 53)
   [yjavac]     .getPassword(user.getUid()), Arrays.asList(authorities));
   [yjavac]                                  ^^^^^^
   [yjavac] Arrays cannot be resolved
   [yjavac] ----------
   [yjavac] ----------
   [yjavac] 469. ERROR in D:\hybris-multichannel-suite-4.7.9\hybris\bin\platform
\ext\servicelayer\src\de\hybris\platform\servicelayer\security\spring\HybrisSess
ionFixationProtectionStrategy.java (at line 97)
   [yjavac]     for (final Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : attributesToMigrate
.entrySet())
   [yjavac]                ^^^^^^^^^
   [yjavac] Map.Entry cannot be resolved to a type
   [yjavac] ----------
   [yjavac] 470. ERROR in D:\hybris-multichannel-suite-4.7.9\hybris\bin\platform
\ext\servicelayer\src\de\hybris\platform\servicelayer\security\spring\HybrisSess
ionFixationProtectionStrategy.java (at line 97)
   [yjavac]     for (final Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : attributesToMigrate
.entrySet())
   [yjavac]
 ^^^^^^^^
   [yjavac] The method entrySet() from the type Map<String,Object> refers to the
 missing type Map$Entry
   [yjavac] ----------
   [yjavac] ----------
   [yjavac] 471. ERROR in D:\hybris-multichannel-suite-4.7.9\hybris\bin\platform
\ext\servicelayer\src\de\hybris\platform\servicelayer\security\spring\vote\Hybri
sNotAnonymousVoter.java (at line 1)
   [yjavac]     /*
   [yjavac]     ^
   [yjavac] The type java.lang.reflect.AnnotatedElement cannot be resolved. It i
s indirectly referenced from required .class files
   [yjavac] ----------
   [yjavac] ----------
   [yjavac] 472. ERROR in D:\hybris-multichannel-suite-4.7.9\hybris\bin\platform
\ext\servicelayer\src\de\hybris\platform\servicelayer\type\impl\DefaultTypeServi
ce.java (at line 0)
   [yjavac]     /*
   [yjavac]     ^
   [yjavac] Internal compiler error: java.lang.NullPointerException at org.eclip
se.jdt.internal.compiler.problem.ProblemReporter.missingTypeInMethod(`enter code here`Unknown Sou
rce)
   [yjavac] ----------`enter code here`
   [yjavac] 473. ERROR in D:\hybris-multichannel-suite-4.7.9\hybris\bin\platform
\ext\servicelayer\src\de\hybris\platform\servicelayer\type\impl\DefaultTypeServi
ce.java (at line 450)
   [yjavac]     for (final Map.Entry<String, Object> e : (Set<Map.Entry<String,
Object>>) comptype.getAllDefaultValues().entrySet())
   [yjavac]                ^^^^^^^^^
   [yjavac] Map.Entry cannot be resolved to a type
   [yjavac] ----------
   [yjavac] 474. ERROR in D:\hybris-multichannel-suite-4.7.9\hybris\bin\platform
\ext\servicelayer\src\de\hybris\platform\servicelayer\type\impl\DefaultTypeServi
ce.java (at line 450)
   [yjavac]     for (final Map.Entry<String, Object> e : (Set<Map.Entry<String,
Object>>) comptype.getAllDefaultValues().entrySet())
   [yjavac]                                                   ^^^^^^^^^
   [yjavac] Map.Entry cannot be resolved to a type
   [yjavac] ----------
   [yjavac] java.lang.NullPointerException
   [yjavac]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.problem.ProblemReporter.mis
singTypeInMethod(Unknown Source)
   [yjavac]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.MessageSend.resolveType
(Unknown Source)
   [yjavac]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.CastExpression.resolveT
ype(Unknown Source)
   [yjavac]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.ForeachStatement.resolv
e(Unknown Source)
   [yjavac]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.Block.resolveUsing(Unkn
own Source)
   [yjavac]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TryStatement.resolve(Un
known Source)
   [yjavac]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.AbstractMethodDeclarati
on.resolveStatements(Unknown Source)
   [yjavac]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.MethodDeclaration.resol
veStatements(Unknown Source)
   [yjavac]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.AbstractMethodDeclarati
on.resolve(Unknown Source)
   [yjavac]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.resolve
(Unknown Source)
   [yjavac]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.resolve
(Unknown Source)
   [yjavac]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.CompilationUnitDeclarat
ion.resolve(Unknown Source)
   [yjavac]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.process(Unknown So
urce)
   [yjavac]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ProcessTaskManager.run(Unkn
own Source)
   [yjavac]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
   [yjavac]

BUILD FAILED
D:\hybris-multichannel-suite-4.7.9\hybris\bin\platform\build.xml:25: The followi
ng error occurred while executing this line:
D:\hybris-multichannel-suite-4.7.9\hybris\bin\platform\resources\ant\compiling.x
ml:47: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\hybris-multichannel-suite-4.7.9\hybris\bin\platform\resources\ant\compiling.x
ml:66: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\hybris-multichannel-suite-4.7.9\hybris\bin\platform\resources\ant\util.xml:24
: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\hybris-multichannel-suite-4.7.9\hybris\bin\platform\resources\ant\compiling.x
ml:68: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\hybris-multichannel-suite-4.7.9\hybris\bin\platform\resources\ant\compiling.x
ml:208: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\hybris-multichannel-suite-4.7.9\hybris\bin\platform\resources\ant\compiling.x
ml:220: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\hybris-multichannel-suite-4.7.9\hybris\bin\platform\resources\ant\compiling.x
ml:241: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\hybris-multichannel-suite-4.7.9\hybris\bin\platform\resources\ant\util.xml:86
: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 34 seconds

D:\hybris-multichannel-suite-4.7.9\hybris\bin\platform>hybrisserver.bat
Used config: D:\hybris-multichannel-suite-4.7.9\hybris\bin\platform\tomcat-6/con
f/wrapper.conf
FATAL  | wrapper  | Failed to load configuration.
An error occurred in the process.
D:\hybris-multichannel-suite-4.7.9\hybris\bin\platform>
```

Comment: Yes, as Stretch said it, I'd check which version of Java is required by this version of Hybris and make sure my JAVA_HOME was point to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ClassNotFound java.util.Arrays? java.util.Map? Those are pretty damn fundamental to Java.

I would say this is totally unrelated to hybris. Try installing Java.

Comment: Hi Streatch and Henrique, thanks so much for your inputs. I tried re-installing java. Eclipse and all other java applications working fine in my computer. Still i am facing same issue. Kindly help me.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you can do after installing Jdk is to delete the hybris setup and re un-zip the hybris folder which effectively deletes the default database - and you can recreate original database state using ant initialize.

Answer (score 0):

These errors coming from the Java Version Issues. If you are using Java earlier versions try to install the new versions like 1.6 or 1.7 so based on that again try to re-run your extensions.
Try to check your  Java Version ant version.

Here you need to do few more steps:

1. delete your Hybris extracted folder and
2. create new folder and
3. Unzip your zip file in to newly created folder then start from the beginning

Answer (score 0):

The end of the pasted output shows the configuration file PATH has the "/" (forward slash) - causing the wrapper FATAL exception when trying to load the configuration file.

- Please use the "\" (slash) instead (see Example).

Example

(from the original post at the end)

```
 D:\hybris-multichannel-suite-4.7.9\hybris\bin\platform>hybrisserver.bat
Used config: D:\hybris-multichannel-suite-4.7.9\hybris\bin\platform\tomcat-6/con
f/wrapper.conf
FATAL  | wrapper  | Failed to load configuration.
An error occurred in the process.
```

NOTE:  The path to *wrapper.conf* has "/" (instead of "\") causing

Please use the correct PATH:
D:\hybris-multichannel-suite-4.7.9\hybris\bin\platform**\tomcat-6\conf\wrapper.conf